# React-testing-library - test if an html element does not exist

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

This is my [live code](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-testing-react-forked-cbd304?file=/src/components/App.js:0-516)

In my current code I have a div with id `#___portal`

```
<div id="___portal"></div>
```

I have a component where I create a portal adding the content to the `#___portal` (in my real code, this div will always be created)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { createPortal } from "react-dom";

const App = ({ children }) => {
  const [portalEl, setPortalEl] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    //in my real code #___portal exists
    setPortalEl(document.getElementById("___portal"));
    console.log(portalEl);
  }, [portalEl]);

  if (!portalEl) return null;

  return createPortal(
    <>
      <div id="modal" role="dialog">
        {children}
      </div>
    </>,
    portalEl
  );
};

export default App;
```

I am trying to do a test where I want to test that a text is contained in the component.
My test fails and I suspect that it is because the content of my component is not being added to the `#___portal` and that is why my component is not rendering, how can I do to simulate this in my test?

```
import App from "./App";
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-testing-library";
describe("<App />", () => {
  it("Should render text", async () => {
    let testId = "___portal";
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.setAttribute("id", testId);
    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

    const text = "hello world";
    const { getByText } = render(
      <App>
        <div>{text}</div>
      </App>
    );
    expect(getByText(text)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});

//output of test
<body>
 <div
  id="___portal"
  />
 <div />
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time your component is rendered for first time `portalEl` is `undefined` and component returns `null`. Since you are getting portal root element in `useEffect` you can use `async/await` helper methods that work with queries to wait for changes in the DOM. But, according to your implementation I think that what you need to do is a small refactor to `App` component:

You don't need to wait for `useEffect` to get `portalEl` because you know it exists beforehand. This way you save an extra render by not calling `setPortalEl`

```
/** checking for object window in case this code runs on server side */
const portalEl = (typeof window !== 'undefined') ? document.getElementById("___portal"): null;

const App = ({ children }) => {

  if (!portalEl) return null;

  return createPortal(
    <>
      <div id="modal" role="dialog">
        {children}
      </div>
    </>,
    portalEl
  );
};
```

or assign its value directly:

```
  const [portalEl] = useState(document.getElementById("___portal"));
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying. It's a long story, but I can't do what you say, this code compiles and I can't have something with `document` outside the useEffect because the build fails (server error).  But I would really need help to correct my test, I need something in my test to help me simulate that this `___portal` element has already been created.

Comment: @yavgz in that case you can check for object window ----> `const portalEl = (typeof window !== 'undefined') ? document.getElementById("___portal"): null;
`

Comment: Doing that, my test not works, do you see my live code? Mi objective is fix my test :O thanks genius

Comment: @yavgz https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-testing-react-forked-equ3j1

Answer (score 2):

When testing react, ANYTHING that happens as the result of a `useEffect` needs to use the [async API](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async). Usually, this is as simple as using the `findBy*` methods instead of the `getBy*` methods. These return a `Promise`, so be sure to `await` it:

```js
expect(await screen.findByText(text)).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Comment: thanks for answerig... do you see my live code? I need fix my test, this line not works for me.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-testing-react-forked-v4btne It runs fine for me. Note that `toBeInTheDocument` is provided by `jest-dom` which wasn't included in your sandbox. That error would surface as "is not a function", though. Any projects created by `create-react-app` or `vite` in the last few years already have that in there. The sandbox is also using `react-testing-library`, which was deprecated 3 years ago in favor of `@testing-library/react`

Comment: your sandbox thows error in the test :(

Comment: What's the error? I click the link, go to the tests tab, and a few seconds later, it goes green. `Test Summary 1 passed 1 total There are no failing tests, congratulations!`